# Access by role based on term referenced in the node

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

I'd like to restrict access to content based on a term referenced in the node.

For example, I have a content type 'submission' and I want users with the role 'curator' to be only able to view nodes that have the taxonomy term 'art'.

Any pointers towards a sustainable solution to this?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting a custom module based solution, Drupal has [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x) which lets any module control access to a certain node. In your case, you want check the `$node` object on a 'view' `$op` and return the appropriate `NODE_ACCESS_*` constant which tells Drupal when the user has access to the node.

```
// @TODO: Replace 2 with your curator RID.
define('MYMODULE_CURATOR_ROLE_ID', 2);

function MYMODULE_has_terms($node) {
  // @TODO: Define logic that checks if node taxonomy field has certain terms.
  return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function test_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  // Only step in when curators are viewing 'submission' nodes 
  // and allow access if a node is tagged with certain terms
  if (is_object($account) && user_has_role(MYMODULE_CURATOR_ROLE_ID, $account) ) {
    if (is_object($node) && $node->type == 'submission' && $op == 'view') {
      return MYMODULE_has_terms($node) ? NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW : NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```